# Going Fullscreen Through MainActivity Crashes the App

Tags: java, android

When I try to make my app full-screen within MainActivity.java, my application is getting crashed. This is what my full screen code is:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

Comment: Add error code please. Without it your question is unclear.

Comment: Remove the first setContentView() and try adding log...

Comment: I think requestWindowFeature must be called before setContentView

Comment: You will get `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content`, if you put `requestWindowFeature` after `setContentView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are calling setContentView two times**

```
//setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //don't call here

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that I had it in there twice.

Answer (score 0):

Please Call these On Above of `super.onCreate` and don't call setcontentview two Remove above..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Please see the doc...

The docs for [Window.requestFeature():](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#requestFeature(int))

> This must be called before setContentView().

Answer (score 0):

Use this

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Answer (score 0):

```
You can to this by two way either from AndroidManifest.xml or Activity itself:

1) To set your App or any individual activity display in Full Screen mode, insert the code:

<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

2) To set your activity as full screen mode write code before onCreate method,You can do it programatically:

public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```